# Define aliases for emoji in GitHub

Tags: github, emoji

Like many of us do, some commits of mine have their message starting with a *tag*  (`[bug]`, `[minor]`, `[docs]`, for example) for helping reading the logs. The idea of decorating them with emojis as implemented by GitHub is quite cool, but not really useful in the command-line.

The (original) name of emojis don't really match their use in this context, if I'm reading my logs from my terminal they should be short and meaningful. For example, I would like to see a `:nail_care:` emoji on my repository webpage for `[minor]` commits (e.g, a house-keeping commit).

That's why I would like to have some web/gui-related aliases, something that maps (e.g.)

- `:minor:` (git message) --> `:nail_care:` (github/web-gui)

Do you know if such solution is possible?